# tips needed to write the function quote this

Tags: python

Write a function called "quote_this" that accepts two
arguments: a string representing a quote (not surrounded
by quotation marks) and a string of a name. The function
should return a new string with the quote surrounded by
quotation marks (") followed by a dash and the given

## name in python.

don't know how to go about starting to solve this.any help

Comment: Can you show any code? Try to declare a function that does it, for instance. What will the arguments be? What will it return?

Comment: All you need to do is to use `+` in this function and it is literally a 1 line function (I won't do your homework for you though).
Best suggestion I can give you is to start using Google.

Comment: That description is _almost_ pseudocode. You can just about literally translate it directly to code. What part of it is giving you trouble? (Also, this sounds like homework. I'd be very surprised if your instructor assigned this task without giving you the necessary tools to complete it.)

Comment: `quote_this = lambda quote, name: '"{}" - {}'.format(quote, name)`

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
def quote_this(quote,name):
    return '"' + quote + '" - ' + name
```

In which quote represents the string of your quote and name the name of the author

Comment: Why solve their homework when they didn't even try to Google?

Answer (score 0):

```
def quote_this(quote_string, name):
    return '\"' + str(quote_string) + '\"' + ' - ' + str(name)

quote_this('this', 'John')
```

You should really look into Google or read a book for this. It's really simple. Also, provide a sample code next time.

Comment: There's no need to escape the double quote between single quotes.